# How save to a file the output for Eclipse (Message) Console?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I have a program that implements the Eclipse Console as follows:

[FAQ How do I write to the console from a plug-in?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F)

Then i use the `(MessageConsole) mainConsole).newMessageStream()` to redirect the OutputStream of a Jsch Channel to my new console.

```
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(((MessageConsole) mainConsole.newMessageStream());

JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
channel.setOutputStream(printStream);
```

Now i want redirect the same OutputStream of the Jsch Channel to a file, the problem is that is already redirect to my console.

How i can do it at the same time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're simply outputting text, you can try :

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");
```

Then, write your String to it, just like you would to any output stream:

```
out.println(text);
```

You'll need exception handling, as ever. Be sure to call out.close() when you've finished writing.

If you are using Java 7 or later, you can use the "try-with-resources statement" which will automatically close your PrintStream when you are done with it (ie exit the block) like so:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt")) {
    out.println(text);
}
```

You will still need to explicitly throw the java.io.FileNotFoundException as before.

Comment: Hi, i edit the question to provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, you have text in your console ? And you want to store this text in a file ?

Comment: Yes, i have the output of the stream that comes from Jsch channel.

Comment: Ok, then all you have to do is stored the text you want in a variable. And then follow the steps I told you in my first comment.